# Git checkout from branch develop and have multiple commit

Tags: git, github

I'm having a problem, after I cloned my project from remote repository.

I create a new branch "develop". Then on develop branch I run

```
git pull origin develop
```

From there I start to checkout other branches for Testing, Bugfix, Feature.

After few days, I notice I got multiple commits with the same message "Merge branch 'develop' of github:abcxyz".

I don't know how to fix this. My previous project when I checkout from branch develop, I only have one commit. I tried to delete the "develop" branch and create a new one but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Say your bug fix branch is called bugfix and you want to merge it into master:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash bugfix
git commit
```

This will take all the commits from the bugfix branch, squash them into 1 commit, and merge it with your master branch.

Comment: No, what i want to do is when i checkout from the develop branch, i dont get multiple (Merge commit) from that branch.